# Columns disappearing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I created in SSRS that up until a few days ago was working fine. I was asked to make some minor changes to it and now two columns in one of my tables is not showing. When I preview it in visual studio everything looks fine. After I distribute it and go to Report Manager the columns are missing. I've never had anything like this happen before. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: It's true, the preview doesn't always show you what the report is going to do when deployed.  I'd check the margins and page dimensions and make sure nothing got shifted over an edge somewhere.

Comment: That's the first thing I looked at. Everything in that respect looks good. Any other Ideas?

Comment: I seem to remember something similar happening and could not find a cause. I think I just deleted the report from the server and redeployed. I *may* have deployed under a different name too. Worth a shot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens to me all of the time. Print preview is my best friend.

I recommend always staying a quarter of an inch away from the edge of the paper size, including margins.

For example, all of my reports have a .5" margin on each size on 8.5" paper. If I put the last edge of my table on 7.5", the last column will be on a different page. If I move it to 7.25" everything will show.

Paginated reports are designed to be printed so if you go outside of your page size (even with whitespace sometimes), it will push things on to other pages.